# How do I run this code in my browser from the VS Code terminal?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I wanted to React-ify this:"https://www.codewall.co.uk/build-your-own-php-fiddle-tutorial/" for a new project. Not even sure if it's possible, but when cloning the code from the repo provided I realized that I don't know the terminal command to run the code. I just want to run the code and be able to view it in the browser. Probably a pretty low iq question but I'm stumped as I've never worked with php before

Comment: I'm guessing you need to setup an apache webserver

Comment: You'll probably need mysql as well. You can install PHP, Apache, & MySQL individually. But you might look up how to install LAMP stack or WAMP stack (LAMP being Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP & WAMP being same but Windows).